# checking for XML Duplicate elements in XSL

Tags: xslt

How to achieve the below conversion of XML file using XSL (need to check for duplicate entries in < OptionData>):

Input XML:

```
<ConfigurationSetDataExtract>
  <SOSData>
    <OptionData>
      <Option Name="Controller Type" Value="Controller Type 1"/>
      <Option Name="Spindle Type" Value="Single"/>
      <Option Name="With Tailstock" Value="True"/>
    </OptionData>
    <VariantItem ItemID="000039"/>
  </SOSData>

  <SOSData>
    <OptionData>
      <Option Name="Integer1" Value="27"/>
      <Option Name="Logical 1" Value="True"/>
      <Option Name="Real 1" Value="56"/>
      <Option Name="String 1" Value="Test"/>
    </OptionData>
    <VariantItem ItemID="000042"/>
  </SOSData>

  <SOSData>
    <OptionData>
      <Option Name="Controller Type" Value="Controller Type 1"/>
      <Option Name="Spindle Type" Value="Four"/>
      <Option Name="With Tailstock" Value="False"/>
    </OptionData>
    <VariantItem ItemID="000040"/> 
  </SOSData>

  <SOSData>
    <OptionData>
      <Option Name="Controller Type" Value="Controller Type 1"/>
      <Option Name="Spindle Type" Value="Single"/>
      <Option Name="With Tailstock" Value="True"/>
    </OptionData>
    <VariantItem ItemID="000041"/>
  </SOSData>
</ConfigurationSetDataExtract>
```

Output XML:

```
<ConfigurationSetDataExtract>
  <SOSData>
    <OptionData>
      <Option Name="Controller Type" Value="Controller Type 1"/>
      <Option Name="Spindle Type" Value="Single"/>
      <Option Name="With Tailstock" Value="True"/>
    </OptionData>
    <VariantItem ItemID="000039"/>
<VariantItem ItemID="000041"/>
  </SOSData>

  <SOSData>
    <OptionData>
      <Option Name="Integer1" Value="27"/>
      <Option Name="Logical 1" Value="True"/>
      <Option Name="Real 1" Value="56"/>
      <Option Name="String 1" Value="Test"/>
    </OptionData>
    <VariantItem ItemID="000042"/>
  </SOSData>

  <SOSData>
    <OptionData>
      <Option Name="Controller Type" Value="Controller Type 1"/>
      <Option Name="Spindle Type" Value="Four"/>
      <Option Name="With Tailstock" Value="False"/>
    </OptionData>
    <VariantItem ItemID="000040"/>
  </SOSData>
</ConfigurationSetDataExtract>
```

The actual XML file has much more data , and hence may have more such similar scenarios and hence needs to be generic.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? SO does not provide code but will help you with questions concerning code. Best regards, Peter

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what version of XSLT. Here is an XSLT 2.0 solution. XSLT 1.0 is possible, but it would be a fair bit of work.

**This XSLT 2.0 stylesheet ...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:so="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432225"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs so">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="so:option-set-value" as="xs:string">
 <xsl:param name="OptionData" as="element(OptionData)" />
 <xsl:variable name="options">
   <xsl:for-each select="$OptionData/Option">
    <xsl:sort select="@Name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@Name,'=',@Value,';')" />
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:value-of select="$options" /> 
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="SOSData" group-by="so:option-set-value( OptionData)">
   <SOSData>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]/OptionData" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/VariantItem" />
   </SOSData>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**... when applied to this document ...**

```
<ConfigurationSetDataExtract>
  <SOSData>
    <OptionData>
      <Option Name="Controller Type" Value="Controller Type 1"/>
      <Option Name="Spindle Type" Value="Single"/>
      <Option Name="With Tailstock" Value="True"/>
    </OptionData>
    <VariantItem ItemID="000039"/>
  </SOSData>

  <SOSData>
    <OptionData>
      <Option Name="Integer1" Value="27"/>
      <Option Name="Logical 1" Value="True"/>
      <Option Name="Real 1" Value="56"/>
      <Option Name="String 1" Value="Test"/>
    </OptionData>
    <VariantItem ItemID="000042"/>
  </SOSData>

  <SOSData>
    <OptionData>
      <Option Name="Controller Type" Value="Controller Type 1"/>
      <Option Name="Spindle Type" Value="Four"/>
      <Option Name="With Tailstock" Value="False"/>
    </OptionData>
    <VariantItem ItemID="000040"/> 
  </SOSData>

  <SOSData>
    <OptionData>
      <Option Name="Controller Type" Value="Controller Type 1"/>
      <Option Name="Spindle Type" Value="Single"/>
      <Option Name="With Tailstock" Value="True"/>
    </OptionData>
    <VariantItem ItemID="000041"/>
  </SOSData>
</ConfigurationSetDataExtract>
```

**... will yield output ...**

```
<ConfigurationSetDataExtract>
   <SOSData>
      <OptionData>
         <Option Name="Controller Type" Value="Controller Type 1"/>
         <Option Name="Spindle Type" Value="Single"/>
         <Option Name="With Tailstock" Value="True"/>
      </OptionData>
      <VariantItem ItemID="000039"/>
      <VariantItem ItemID="000041"/>
   </SOSData>
   <SOSData>
      <OptionData>
         <Option Name="Integer1" Value="27"/>
         <Option Name="Logical 1" Value="True"/>
         <Option Name="Real 1" Value="56"/>
         <Option Name="String 1" Value="Test"/>
      </OptionData>
      <VariantItem ItemID="000042"/>
   </SOSData>
   <SOSData>
      <OptionData>
         <Option Name="Controller Type" Value="Controller Type 1"/>
         <Option Name="Spindle Type" Value="Four"/>
         <Option Name="With Tailstock" Value="False"/>
      </OptionData>
      <VariantItem ItemID="000040"/>
   </SOSData>
</ConfigurationSetDataExtract>
```

### Note

If you could guarantee that all the options would always be in the same order by name, this stylesheet could be vastly simplified. Let us know if this is the case.

---

## Another XSLT 2.0 solution.

Although not efficient at scale, this alternative XSLT 2.0 solution should get marks for beauty. It is functionally equivalent to the first given solution.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl fn">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="SOSData" group-by="
    fn:string-join(
    for $z in (
      for $i in (0 to count(OptionData/Option) - 1) return
       for $x in OptionData/Option return
        if (  $i = count(
             for $y in OptionData/Option return
               if ($y/@Name lt $x/@Name)
                 then $y
                 else ()
             )
           )
          then $x
          else ()   
      ) return concat($z/@Name,'=',$z/@Value),';')">
   <SOSData>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]/OptionData ,
                                  current-group()/VariantItem" />
   </SOSData>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XPath 2 sorting technique comes from the brilliant [Pavel Hlousek](http://www.ximeco.org/Xime/XPathCanSortHlousek.pdf). Thanks Pavel.

---

### XSLT 1.0 Solution

**Here is the equivalent XSLT 1.0 solution...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:esl="http://exslt.org/common"
  xmlns:so="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432225"
  exclude-result-prefixes="so xsl esl ">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:key name="option-set" match="SOSData" use="@so:key" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="phase-1">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="phase-1" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="phase-2">
 <xsl:element name="{name()}">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="phase-2" />
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|processing-instruction()|comment()" mode="phase-2">
 <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SOSData" mode="phase-1">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:variable name="options">
   <xsl:for-each select="OptionData/Option">
    <xsl:sort select="@Name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@Name,'=',@Value,';')" />
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:attribute name="so:key"><xsl:value-of select="$options" /></xsl:attribute> 
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="phase-1" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="phase-1-result">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="phase-1" />
  </xsl:variable>  
  <xsl:apply-templates select="esl:node-set($phase-1-result)/*" mode="phase-2" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[SOSData]" mode="phase-2">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::SOSData)]" mode="phase-2" /> 
   <xsl:for-each select="SOSData[ generate-id() =
                                  generate-id( key('option-set', @so:key)[1])]">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="phase-2" />                                
   </xsl:for-each>                                 
 </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SOSData" mode="phase-2">
  <SOSData>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|(key('option-set', @so:key)/VariantItem)" mode="phase-2" />
  </SOSData>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@so:*" mode="phase-2" />


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry I forgot to mention the version of XSLT. Its actually 1.0

Comment: @user2715934 Please find XSLT 1.0 solution appended.